# Замена html с помощью функции preg_replace

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток.

у меня есть html

```html
<a href="https://test.com" title="Description: " data-title="FWsffAFWfvngFrQcA=" data-description="">10-dithering-opt.jpg</a>
```

Данных ссылок на странице будет много

Как мне изменить через функцию preg_replace данную структуру на

```html
<span>10-dithering-opt.jpg</span>
```

Извините, просто не умею работать с регулярками

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью захватывающих скобок `(...)` с последующей заменой найденной подстроки:

```
$str = '<a href="https://test.com" title="Description: " data-title="FWsffAFWfvngFrQcA=" data-description="">10-dithering-opt.jpg</a>';

$patt = '~<a[^>]+>(.+?)</a>~';
$repl = '<span>$1</span>';

echo preg_replace($patt, $repl, $str);
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Вы мне очень помогли