# Использование preg_match для записи другого значения вместо паттерна

Tags: php

Можно ли в последствии выполнения функции preg_match получить истину или ложь в зависимости от проверенного паттерна? Или же записать вместо патерна, в случае его совпадения, другое значение?
Пример: Если в документе найдена строчка кода `<div class="bg-black">1</div>` то мы записываем куда либо число 1, если вместо этого найдена строчка кода `<div class="bg-black">2</div>` то мы записываем 2, и т.д.

Comment: Пример бы привели, пока похоже на то что вам нужна функция preg_replace

Comment: @Shosty "_Можно ли в последствии выполнения функции preg_match получить истину или ложь в зависимости от проверенного паттерна?_" - да

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Замена html с помощью функции preg\_replace](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768404/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-html-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-preg-replace)

Answer (score 0):

Для обработки html лучше использовать html parser. Например, так:

```
$s = '
    <p>Все, что угодно, до</p>
    <div class="bg-black">1</div>
    <p>Все, что угодно, после</p>';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($s);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="bg-black"]') as $div)
{
    echo $div->nodeValue; // 1
}
```